# Animated.View style not changing even thought the value of animation variable is getting updated

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want the text to move up when i click it. But even though the topPosition value is updated on click to -40, the View doesnt ever move. How can I make the animation run?

```
const TabButton = () => {
  //Animation variables
  const topPosition = useRef(new Animated.Value(1)).current;
  const labelVisibility = useRef(false);

  const pushIconUp = () => {
    console.log('dwad');
    Animated.timing(topPosition, {
      toValue: -40,
      duration: 1000,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
    console.log(topPosition);
  };
  const pushIconDown = () => {
    Animated.timing(topPosition, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 100,
      useNativeDriver: false,
    }).start();
  };

  return (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={pushIconUp}>
      <Animated.View style={{marginTop: topPosition, borderColor: 'white'}}>
        <Text>daw</Text>
      </Animated.View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
  );
};

export default TabButton;
```

Comment: It works on my setup. I click the button and it moves with a animation to the top. What does happen on your setup?

Comment: @DavidScholz It does absolutely nothing. It logs that the value of topPosition has changed but the button doesn't move

Comment: @DavidScholz I am using this component as a tabBarIcon in the Bottom Navigation. Can that be the cause of it not working?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better if you animate the translation instead and also the `TouchableOpacity` should be inside the `Animated.View`.

```
<Animated.View style={{ transform: [{ translateY: topPosition }], borderColor: 'white'}}>
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={pushIconUp}>
        <Text>daw</Text>
    </TouchableHighlight>
</Animated.View>
```

You can also enable `useNativeDriver`

Comment: I've tried translation, opacity, margins. None of the styles work in the animation. The button remains as it is. I also tried putting TouchableHighlight inside Animated.View, but no change